# Store and read Streamdata

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a workerprocess which generates a continuous Text Log (until it is finished). I send this Log to a Webserver, which should store this log. At the same time it should be possible for an user to view this log in real Time by using a different Webserver interface.

Actually I have a HashMap where Key is an ID and the value is a StringBuilder where I append the Data any time there comes a new log row.

The Problem is, that any process uses this HashMap and I am afraid when there will be more simultaneous processes and many users who want to read the log.

What would be a better approach for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all requests to Webserver are made in different threads, problem could occur when:

- one thread will **write** to `StringBuilder`
- another thread will **read** same `StringBuilder`.

Easiest solution: use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`, because all its methods are synchronized.

Comment: I am allready using a `concurrentHashMap` where the `StringBuilder` is in it. So i think i don't need to use StringBuffer? But i think everything will get throttled down when many threads use the same `concurrentHashMap`. How can i avoid this?

Comment: Your approach would work if `StringBuilder` would be immutable. But the problem is that instance inside the map is **mutable**. When writing thread get instance from a Map, it start to mutate it. In same time another thread can read it. So `ConcurrentMap` cannot help in this situation.

Comment: Regarding performance of `ConcurrentHashMap`: do not worry, it is efficient enough.